# setOptions (numericSymbols) in rCharts

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am using rCharts to plot some large values and rather than a value of '1B' (for billion) on the axis label, I am getting '1G' (for Giga). I have seen that the way to change this in highCharts is via the [numericSymbol](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.numericSymbols) option, however I have not been able to do incorporate this into R.

A minimal example is as follows

```
library(rCharts)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:40, y = 2^(1:40))
a <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()
a$series(data=toJSONArray2(data, json=F), type = 'scatter')
a$yAxis(type = 'logarithmic', labels = 
      list(useHTML = T, 
           formatter = "#! function() 
            {
              if (this.value < 1e3) {
                return  this.value;
              } else if (this.value < 1e6){
                return this.value/1e3+'k';
              } else if (this.value < 1e9){
                return this.value/1e6+'M';
              } else if (this.value < 1e12){
                return this.value/1e9+'B';
              } else if (this.value < 1e15){
                return this.value/1e12+'T';
              } else if (this.value >= 1e15){
                return this.value/1e15+'P';
              } else {return this.value};
            } !#")
)
a
```

But I am still getting labels of '1G' on my y-axis for values of about one billion. Is there an error when I set the values of a$lang? Or is there some alternative way to get a 'B' instead of a 'G'?

Comment: How about using a label formatter and there use function which calculates letter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @SebastianBochan however I couldn't find the function which calculates the letter, however I used a bit of an old fashioned technique, which I've added to the original code. If anyone can see a less pedantic way of doing this please let me know.